# JQPlot dates on x axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

Im using JQPLot for a plot but the x-axes definition for dates is not working...

I have used the below option,

```
        axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
```

but still it fails..Any inputs?

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="c:/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="c:/jquery/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="c:/jquery/dist/plugins/jqplot.bubbleRenderer.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" hrf="c:/jquery/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    //var arr = [[11, 123, 1236, "Acura"], [45, 92, 1067, "Alfa Romeo"],
    //[24, 104, 1176, "AM General"], [50, 23, 610, "Aston Martin Lagonda"],
    //[18, 17, 539, "Audi"], [7, 89, 864, "BMW"], [2, 13, 1026, "Bugatti"]];

    //var arr = [[100,158.73,1,{"label":"WINNER, INC."}]
        //,[200,58.73,1,{"label":"A, INC."}]
        //,[300,358.73,1,{"label":"B, INC."}]
    //,[400,458.73,1,{"label":"C, INC."}]]

    var arr = [["2013-08-19",158.73,1,{"label":"WINNER, INC."}]
        ,["2011-0-19",58.73,1,{"label":"A, INC."}]
        ,["2012-08-19",,358.73,1,{"label":"B, INC."}]
    ,["2018-08-19",,458.73,1,{"label":"C, INC."}]]






    plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv',[arr],{
        title: 'Transparent Bubbles',
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
            axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer}},
            rendererOptions: {
                bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
                highlightAlpha: 0.8
            },
            shadow: true,
            shadowAlpha: 0.05
        },


    });
});


</script>

<div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *but still it fails*: Define *fails*. How does it fail? What happens?

Comment: Look at the [docs](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/date-axes.php): *Note, although jqPlot will parse most any human readable date, it is safest to use javascript time stamps when possible. Also, it is best to specify a date and time and not just a date alone. This is due to inconsistent browser handling of local time vs. UTC with bare dates.* Maybe try using time stamps? Or at least include a time with your dates?

Comment: Matt: I don't see anything in x axes

Answer (score 2):

[**jsFiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/cDMYK/2/)

**html:**

```
<div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px; "></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var arr = [
        ["2013-08-19 4:00PM", 158.73,1, {
            "label": "WINNER, INC."
        }],
        ["2011-08-19 4:00PM", 58.73,1, {
            "label": "A, INC."
        }],
        ["2012-08-19 4:00PM", 358.73,1, {
            "label": "B, INC."
        }],
        ["2018-08-19 4:00PM", 458.73,1, {
            "label": "C, INC."
        }]
    ]

    plot1 = $.jqplot('chartdiv', [arr], {
        title: 'Transparent Bubbles',
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
            }
        },
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BubbleRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                bubbleAlpha: 0.6,
                highlightAlpha: 0.8
            },
            shadow: true,
            shadowAlpha: 0.05
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but the the same code does not work in my browser...I downloaded jqplot from http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/download/...jquery.jqplot.1.0.4r1121.zip...I need

Comment: @user1050619, this example uses jqPlot 1.0.8r1250. Is jsFiddle not working or your app? I ask because probably you missed the reference to `jqplot.DateAxisRenderer`. And also remove duplicate references to jquery and reorder all references: `*.css`, `jquery`, `jquery.ui`, `jqplot`, `jqplot.DateAxisRenderer`, `jqplot.BubbleRenderer`.

Comment: ,Yes, fiddle is not working for me...Here is the link ....http://jsfiddle.net/Ren9x/

Comment: @user1050619, your fiddle doesn't include any reference to jqPlot or its plugins

Comment: @user1050619, but with references it shows the legend of chart

Comment: @Nicolai...How do I include the plugins..I have selected everything as you have set...

Comment: @user1050619, look at "External Resources" in sidebar

Comment: Thanks Nicolai..It worked...Now, I have added a label below but its not working properly..Do you want to open a new issue?

Comment: @user1050619, no matter, we can go to the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55781/discussion-between-user1050619-and-nicolai).